# Execute command in terminal via R: how to quote correctly?

Tags: r

I want to execute a line on a remote server:

```
ssh user@machine 'for i in 1 2; do echo "$i"; done'
```

How do I send this command to the server via R with the `system()` command?
The problem is that `system()` needs a string encapsulated in quotation marks and if I quote the above line, the quotation marks cancel each other out.

Comment: what did you try? Please share the exact R code

Comment: I originally just tried to quote the above string: system("ssh user@machine 'for i in 1 2; do echo "$i"; done'")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try escaping the quotes:

```
ssh user@machine 'for i in 1 2; do echo \"$i\"; done'
```

I am running Windows and I don't have a command line tool called `ssh`, however I tried the following code:

```
> system("java \"-version\"")
java version "1.8.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)
```

You will notice that I put escaped quotes around the `-version` parameter and the command ran without any problem.  You can try something similar with `ssh` and it should work.  Of course, you should verify that the command works running from a bash shell first before you try it in R.

Comment: system("ssh user@machine 'for i in 1 2; do echo \"$i\"; done'") works perfectly, thank you!